# Warning! Error encountered during contract execution [Bad jump destination] / missing ETH

Tags: bad-jump

Can some one please advise if I understand this correctly.

This evening, I received the above error warning with a transaction.

The relevant ETH is currently missing from my wallet.

Do I understand correctly that the missing ETH will automatically find its way back to my wallet in due course or is there a process or procedure I need to follow to recover my missing ETH.

Many thanks in advance.

Lance

Answer (score 1):

Receiving this error means that the ETH never actually left your wallet. The transaction could not be executed, so the ether should still sit in your wallet.

Did you try moving ether from an exchange to another wallet? In this case you might need to get in contact with the support team from the exchange, to make sure they re-credit you the ETH from the failed transaction.